A guess about sudoku-like game, proof or a counterexample
A friend of mine came up with a guess, and
neither he nor I could give a proof or a counterexample
of this guess. (we haven't verified it with brute force algorithm)
but we hope to prove it without brute force.
Rule
Consider a $4\times 4$ board, and we need to fill the
board with $1,2,3,4$ and each number should appear exactly
once in each column and row.
Guess
Denote the set of all solutios as $S$ and the entry at the
$i$th row and $j$th column of solution $A$ as $A[i,j]$.
we guess:
$
\forall A,B \in S$, there are always two different locations $(i,j)$
and $(m,n)$
such that $(A[i,j]=A[m,n]) \land (B[i,j]=B[m,n])$ is True.
Example
Here're two solutions:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix},
B=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}
$$
and, $A[1,1]=A[4,4], B[1,1]=B[4,4]$.
Attempt
As the solution $A,B$ are random picked. WLOG, let $A$ be the matrix
in the example above, if $B$ is a counterexample then its entries should
differs whenever the corresponding ones in $A$ are the same.
to make clear our attempt,
let $X=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$, then $A=4X^{3}+3X^{2}+2X+I$, so it's clear
where entries in $A$ are the same. WLOG, let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & * & * & * \\ * & 2 & * & * \\ * & * & 3 & * \\ * & * & * & 4 \\\end{bmatrix}$,
then our goal is use the permutation of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to fill the positions
of $1$s in the power of $X$. like, for $B[2,1]$ and $B[4,3]$ they should tiher be $3$ or $4$. so maybe the permutation should follow the pattern of $\{1,3,2,4\}$? I guess it's possibly relate to abstract algebra?
but i never learned it before... so i get stuck here.
and if it's true, does it still hold for $n \times n$ board?

This is called a "latin square," for what it is worth.

"$
\forall A,B \in S, \exists (i,j),(m,n) \in {1,2,3,4}\times {1,2,3,4}
$
such that $(A[i,j]=A[m,n]) \land (B[i,j]=B[m,n])$ is True"
That's a hard-to-read way to say what you intend, and not even what you intended to say, since for $i=m$, $n=j$ this is obvious. How about
"There are always two different locations $(i,j)$ and $(m,n)$ such that $A[i,j]=A[m,n]$ and $B[i,j]=B[m,n]$"

@JiK Good advice !

@syqwq Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!  Thanks for posting such an interesting question.

Counter-example: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&4&3\\3&4&1&2\\4&3&2&1\end{pmatrix}\\
B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&4&1&2\\4&3&2&1\\2&1&4&3\end{pmatrix}$$
These are a pair of "orthogonal latin squares," and there is a standard way for come up with orthoganal $n\times n$ latin squares when $n$ is a prime power. Indeed, there is a third square $C$ which is also orthogonal to both $A$ and $B:$
$$C=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\4&3&2&1\\2&1&4&3\\3&4&1&2
\end{pmatrix}$$
In fact, you can re-phrase your conjecture as

There does not exist a pair of orthogonal $4\times 4$ latin squares.

There are pairs of orthogonal $n\times n$ latin squares for any $n\neq2,6,$ but finding them in the case $n\equiv 2\pmod4$ was hard. There was a famous conjecture that there were none when $n\equiv2\pmod 4,$ because there were no such for $n=2,6$ and nobody had constructed any for $10$ or higher, so it is a case of a conjecture that was based on two values that was completely wrong for all others.

(I use lower case latin because the book I learned them from said that was traditional, but that was a long time ago, and Wikipedia uses Latin.)

thank you !!!! i don’t know about this before ☺️☺️☺️
